# Clearing azure service bus queue in one go

Tags: .net, azure, queue, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

We are using a service bus queue in our project. We are in need of a functionality to remove all the messages from the queue when the administrator chooses to clear the queue. I searched on the net but could not find any function which does this inside the `QueueClient` class.

Do I have to pop all the messages one by one and then marking them complete to clear the queue or is there a better way?

```
QueueClient queueClient = _messagingFactory.CreateQueueClient(
                              queueName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);

BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage = queueClient.Receive();

while (brokeredMessage != null )
{
    brokeredMessage.Complete();
    brokeredMessage = queueClient.Receive();
}
```

Comment: I recently faced the same issue, and deleting and recreating was not an option, looping works, but is slow, however, using the `PrefetchCount` member of the `QueueClient` you can easily batch a few thousand messages in a single round-trip, speeding things up tremendously: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.prefetchcount.aspx

Answer (score 29):

You can simply do this from azure portal.

If you are not worried about queue messages stored in past 14 days (default) and wanted to clear queue immediately then change message time to live value to 5 or 10 seconds and wait for 5-10 seconds.

**Important step:** After a few seconds, try to receive from queue to force it to update.

All queue messages will be cleared. you can again reset original value. default is 14 days.

[image]

Comment: First, be sure that dead lettering on message expiration is OFF.  After that, this solution works a charm, and it deletes messages much faster than any solution which attempts to "read the queue dry".  Using it, I deleted 1M messages from a queue in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 13):

Using the `Receive()` method within the while loop like you are will cause your code to run indefinitely once the queue is empty, as the `Receive()` method will be waiting for another message to appear on the queue.

If you want this to run automatically, try using the `Peek()` method.

For example:

```
while (queueClient.Peek() != null)
{
    var brokeredMessage = queueClient.Receive();
    brokeredMessage.Complete();
}
```

You can make this simpler again with the `ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete` as was mentioned by hocho.

Comment: A few concerns: (1) Peek will get scheduled, future messages that Receive will not which will cause your app to hang waiting for scheduled messages. (2) Each Peek moves to the next message regardless of it's status so if you Abandon the first message instead of Complete, the 2nd Peek will get the 2nd message but the 2nd Receive will reprocess the 1st. This causes Peek to be offset from Receive by one message and will leave one message unprocessed at the end of your queue for each abandoned message.

Comment: +1 @JustinJStark  When testing this code (as is, no processing, just receive and complete) against a queue that was not receiving new messages, it always failed to completely clear the queue.  It was only clearing 50-75% of the messages.  I would not use this approach to clear a queue.

Comment: This is not the QueueClient found in Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, is it? I am having difficulty finding Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging which has the QueueClient with the CreateReceiver method...

Answer (score 8):

The first I thought I had when I read the question was why not delete and recreate the queue? That could be an approach. But if don't want to do that, you can receive and delete each message until there's no message left.

You can use the latest Azure Service Bus .NET library [Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus#azure-service-bus-client-library-for-net) for both approaches.

1. Delete and recreate queue using `AdministrationClient`

```cs
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration;

ServiceBusAdministrationClient adminClient = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient("<connectionstring>");
await adminClient.DeleteQueueAsync("myqueue");          
await adminClient.CreateQueueAsync("myqueue");
```

Note: `ServiceBusAdministrationClient` is for CRUD operations on an already *existing* Service Bus namespace. If you also need the ability to create a namespace, use the [Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.servicebus?view=azure-dotnet) library instead.

2. Receive and delete until there's no message

```cs
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;

await using var client = new ServiceBusClient("<connectionstring>");
                
ServiceBusReceiver receiver = client.CreateReceiver("myqueue", 
    new ServiceBusReceiverOptions { ReceiveMode = ServiceBusReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete });

while ((await receiver.PeekMessageAsync()) != null)
{
    // receive in batches of 100 messages.
    await receiver.ReceiveMessagesAsync(100);
}
```

`ReceiveMode = ServiceBusReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete` is self-explanatory. The default receive mode is `PeekLock` which doesn't actually remove messages from the queue - it tells Service Bus that the receiving client wants to [settle](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-transfers-locks-settlement#settling-receive-operations) the received messages explicitly. The lock part means competing receivers can't access the message for the duration of the lock.

Comment: Primary reason I can think of for not wanting to delete/recreate is if you used terraform (or alternative) to deploy your stuff and this would get it out of sync.

Answer (score 7):

Using :

- Both approach (from @ScottBrady and @participant)
- And the [MessageReceiver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagereceiver.aspx) abstraction

you can write a method that empty a service bus queue or a topic/subscription:

```
MessageReceiver messageReceiver = ...
while (messageReceiver.Peek() != null)
{
    // Batch the receive operation
    var brokeredMessages = messageReceiver.ReceiveBatch(300);

    // Complete the messages
    var completeTasks = brokeredMessages.Select(m => Task.Run(() => m.Complete())).ToArray();

    // Wait for the tasks to complete. 
    Task.WaitAll(completeTasks);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm having good results using a combination of [ReceiveAndDelete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements#receive-mode), [PrefetchCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements#prefetching), [ReceiveBatchAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagereceiver.receivebatchasync?view=azure-dotnet), and a simple truth loop rather than using Peek. Example with MessagingFactory below:

```
var receiverFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString("ConnString");
var receiver = receiverFactory.CreateMessageReceiver("QName", ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);
receiver.PrefetchCount = 300;

bool loop = true;
while (loop)
{
    var messages = await receiver.ReceiveBatchAsync(300, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    loop = messages.Any();
}
```

Only requires the [WindowsAzure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/) Nuget package.

Answer (score 2):

For Azure-ServiceBus-Queues there is a [`ReceiveBatch`-method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj673154.aspx) which allows you to receive a batch of *n*-messages at the time. Combined with `ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete` you can clear the queue more efficiently.

**Caveat** The number *n* of messages might be returned but it's not guaranteed. Also there is a limit for the message-batch size of [256K](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh528527.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to clean a Azure ServiceBus Queue is to set a very short `DefaultMessageTimeToLive`, wait a few second, try receive from queue from force it to update then restore the initial `DefaultMessageTimeToLive`.

You can do it from the portal or from code :

```
var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
var queueDescription = _namespaceManager.GetQueue(queueName);
var queueClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName, ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);

var dl = queueDescription.EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration;
var ttl = queueDescription.DefaultMessageTimeToLive;

queueDescription.EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration = false;
queueDescription.DefaultMessageTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

Thread.Sleep(5000);
var dumy = queueClient.ReceiveBatch(200, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).ToArray();

queueDescription.EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration = dl;
queueDescription.DefaultMessageTimeToLive = ttl;
```

Comment: Hi Florent,  Not sure if the api changed, but I just tried this on my queue and it had zero changes.  Same messages in queue before and after.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple `Clear()` method to clear the entire queue if you are using the WindowsAzure.Storage library from nuget.  I use the `Microsoft.Windows.Azure.Queue` class from that library to manage the queue.  Otherwise, you can access via their API [per their documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Clear-Messages?redirectedfrom=MSDN).  I don't know how long the method has been in the Azure library and it probably didn't exist when the question was originally asked, but the REST API stems back from at least 2014 per [this Azure feedback post](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/2723677-clear-all-message-from-queue)

The full .NET code to clear the queue with the Azure library is:

```
string connectionString = "YourAzureConnectionStringHere";
string queueName = "YourWebJobQueueName";
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

// Create the queue client, then get a reference to queue
CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference(GetQueueName(queueName));

// Clear the entire queue
queue.Clear();
```

Comment: The original question was about clearing an Azure Service Bus Queue, not an ordinary Azure Queue.

Comment: According to Microsoft, both Azure Service Bus Queue and Azure Queue support the .clear function: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/2723677-clear-all-message-from-queue

Comment: Not in the .NET Core version of the client (i.e. Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus). That does not contain the Clear() method.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Queue Service REST API (not tested).

> The Clear Messages operation deletes all messages from the specified
> queue
>
> DELETE    https://myaccount.queue.core.windows.net/myqueue/messages
>
> Only the account owner may call this operation.

PS. The URL seems to be wrong. Try this instead: https://myaccount.servicebus.windows.net/myqueue/messages

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/clear-messages

Or...

2. Create a logic app to delete messages one by one in a loop (tested).

[image]

Comment: That's not servicebus, that's queue storage, right?